# How to validate multiple Edit text? I'm using TextUtils can only get 1 text

Tags: java, android, validation

How to validate & confirm all the data have value then only it stores data?
Because I wrote `TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Name.getText())`then Store data, It will only validate one. I wanted to validate all the Edittext has value then only allow to store all data. I can't put `else if` as it will go one by one ONCE I clicked the Save Button. Is there any clue?  Thanks in advance...

[image: Here Is the Image]

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
public void setOnClick() {
    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Name.getText())){
                    e_Name.setError("INSERT NAME");
                }else{
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(e_Txn.getText().toString(),
                            e_Name.getText().toString(),
                            e_Amount.getText().toString(),
                            Display_date.getText().toString().trim(),
                            e_Description.getText().toString(),
                            Description.getSelectedItem().toString());

                    if (isInserted == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check each and every one with an `if` and not `if else` statement like this:

```
boolean allValid = true;

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Name.getText())) {
    allValid = false;
    // do other stuff
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Amount.getText())) {
    allValid = false;
    // do other stuff
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Description.getText())) {
    allValid = false;
    // do other stuff
}
// finally do what you want if allValid = false
if (!allValid) {
    // your code
} else {
    // all fields are valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You may try this code**. May be there is no other way to validate all at once.

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Name.getText().toString()) ||
  TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Amount.getText().toString()) ||
  TextUtils.isEmpty(Display_date.getText().toString()) ||
  TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Description.getText().toString()) ||
  TextUtils.isEmpty(Description.getSelectedItem().toString())){
  //Some edittext has no value
  //Warning the field!
}else {
//Do your job here
}
```

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't work. maybe something wrong, i can't either put || or &&.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be

```
if(isValid()){
  // process data here
}
```

Make this method.

```
private boolean isValid(){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(e_Name.getText())){
       e_Name.setError("this field can not be blank");
       return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et_amount.getText())){
       et_amount.setError("this field can not be blank");
       return false;
    } else if (...) so on 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Here my Code**

```
   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(Validations.validateForNull(edit_fname, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.empty_first_name)));
            {
                if(Validations.validateForNull(edit_lname, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.empty_last_name)))
                {
                    if(Validations.validateEmail(edit_email ,mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.empty_email_msg), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_email_msg)))
                    {

                        if (Validations.validateForNull(edit_mobile_no, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.empty_phone_number)))
                        {
                            if (Utils.isConnectingToInternet(mContext)){
                                checkProviderExistApi();

                            }
                            else {
                                Utils.showShortToast(mContext,"Internet not connected");
                            }

                              email=edit_email.getText().toString();
                              String phn=edit_mobile_no.getText().toString();
                              number=phn.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                              Log.e("number--",""+number);
                              first_name=edit_fname.getText().toString();
                              last_name=edit_lname.getText().toString();

                        }else {
                            check_phone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }else {
                        check_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Validations is my utils class i think it helps you.